# How to get post request data by web view in android

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to capture post request data by web view in my android(nativescript) app but `shouldInterceptRequest` from `android.webkit.WebViewClient.extend` only provides `getUrl, getMethod` and `getRequestHeaders` methods. Is there any way to get the post request data?

Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36918490. Currently, you can use this library to capture POST: https://github.com/KonstantinSchubert/request_data_webviewclient

Comment: Thank you for providing these links. A beautifull solution.

Comment: Can you guide me how to include this in nativescript android app? because I tried to follow the steps given but unable to configure.